# How to use a Storyboard

Tags: windows-phone-7, storyboard

I wish to stop using the DispatcherTimer to show animations as that is extremely unpredictable. Instead, I want to start using a Storyboard as that is apparently the best and most efficient way to animate controls.

I have tried searching for Tutorials but have not, unfortunately, stumbled on one yet.

Can anyone please advise me where to begin? For example, "moving an image across the screen" and then "moving many images at the same time whilst rotating them".

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of information out there regarding Storyboard animation in windows phone 7.  Here are a couple of links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard(v=vs.95).aspx

http://www.silverlight.net/learn/creating-ui/animation-and-easing/animations-(silverlight-quickstart)

**Here is some code to get you started**

This will animate a simple rectangle, moving it back and forth across the screen.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="PhoneApp1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Rectangle x:Name="rect" Height="25" Width="25" Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="transform" />
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <Rectangle.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Rectangle.Loaded">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="transform"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                                    From="0" To="100" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Rectangle.Triggers>
            </Rectangle>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>


</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Comment: I am not that "advanced" to simply digest the information stored on the MSDN website. I have to mostly look at real code, analyse and understand it. Then put it in to practise. The second link you provided seems really good. I'll check it out. Thank you Sir.

Comment: No problem. Please see my edit for a simple example to get you started.

Comment: There are no triggers in Windows Phone. The code is fro WPF not Windows Phone.

Comment: @KateBrown, There are triggers in windows phone.  What version are you on?